# Can't Access cookie from response object

Tags: angular

Angular 4

I am trying to access my cookies from the response object. I have tried, res.headers.getAll('set-cookie')... res.headers.getAll('CookieName');, document.cookie. None of which seem to work.

The cookie is shown in the response object but not within the browser/application cookie storage.

My headers also have { withCredentials: true }

Comment: Why the Angular tag?

Comment: beacuse it is angular 2+???

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`document.cookies` will give you the cookies that were set for *the current origin* at *the time the page was loaded*.

The XMLHttpRequest and fetch APIs forbid reading the cookie information directly.

You'll need to pass the data using some other method (e.g. in the response body or a custom response header) if you want to make it available to JS.

Comment: Could it not be related to the path of the cookie, It it shown in my response object but not stored automatically within the browsers storage. The path is not set to '/'

Answer (score 0):

It was the cookie path, we changed the cookie path to the correct path for it to work.